# stuck at robozzle 1251

Tags: algorithm

Can anyone help me solve this robozzle? It is called bigPlus id 1251
http://www.robozzle.com/puzzle.aspx?id=1251
[image: robozzle 1251]

Comment: for more reference http://www.robozzle.com/puzzle.aspx?id=1251

Comment: Cool game! Thanks for reference.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Can you add an explanation of the rules and goal for this puzzle?

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this puzzle involves a new tool that you probably haven't used yet.

It's called:

> Painting

Once you do that, and know how it works the solution becomes more straightforward.

Solution:

> F1: GreyPaintRed, GreyF2
>  F2: GreyForward, GreenLeft, GreenLeft, RedRight, GreyF2